# spring boot : automatic renew of letsencrypt certificate

Tags: spring, boot

i have a published spring boot app (http) and i want to secure it with HTTPS..

there are many tutorials on how to create a letsencrypt certificate and import it into the /resources folder of the spring boot app, to make the certificate work.

the letsencrypt certificate is only valid for three months.. and i would have to import the certificate and restart my spring boot application every time..

of course, certbot can automatically renew the letsencrypt certificate, but…

is there a way to do this task automatically (import and restart)?
are there any alternative ways to do this (without importing and restarting)?

Comment: Usually the platform you deploy to will take care of the cert. For example, Netlify does this automatically. I'm not sure why you think your application will need to be restarted. The certificate is stored on the file system, and used to communicate with the client. It's got nothing to do with the JVM.

Comment: i have just a VM with Debian Linux 11, and java 11, where my spring boot app runs.. no cloud platform

Comment: If it’s your homegrown system, then you gotta do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this github project will do exactly what you need:

https://github.com/valb3r/letsencrypt-helper

It operates a webserver to complete the HTTP-01 challenge automatically and renew the certificate without an application restart. All you need to do, is open port 80.